# Combine two python mysql queries with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to grab some specific rows of two tables before and after a certain time, this is my code:

```
mysql_query = """
select tb1x.id
from table1 as tb1x 
join table2 as tb2x ON tb2x.id = tb1x.cid
where tb1x.created > CURDATE()
UNION ALL
(select tb1y.id
from table1 as tb1y 
join table2 as tb2y ON tb2y.id = tb1y.cid
where tb1y.created < CURDATE()
)
where tb2x.id=tb2y.id
ORDER BY tb1y.created DESC;"""
```

It gives an error and indicates that UNION is not used properly.

and I guess the problem could be here: `AND tb2x.id=tb2y.id`
Could you please help where is the problem or if it's an smart way to compare two different sections of a table?

Comment: Are you sure you want a `UNIION` and not something like a JOIN?

Comment: Put the individual select queries inside parentheses `(..)`. Due to order by clause, MySQL is unable to interpret properly.

Comment: Not sure about UNION but I want different tb1x.ids after and before a certain time

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya then does query realizes `AND tb2x.id=tb2y.id`?

Comment: Yes. There must be parentheses around the individual selects .. like : `(select .... Where..) union (select ... Where...) order by..`

Comment: but still says "check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE tb2x.id=tb2y.id..."..

Comment: The problem is that your SQL is so syntactically incorrect that, speaking for myself, it is impossible to guess what it is you are trying to accomplish. Your best shot is to explain in English what it is you are trying to accomplish. It can never hurt to describe the tables (column definitions), provide sample data and show expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UNION` doesn't permits any comparison between columns, so `where tb2x.id=tb2y.id` after a `UNION` is an error

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_operations_(SQL)#UNION_operator

To compare two different sections of a table you have to `JOIN` itself:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
       SELECT
         tb1x.id,
         tb1x.created
       FROM table1 AS tb1x
         JOIN table2 AS tb2x
           ON tb2x.id = tb1x.cid
       WHERE tb1x.created > CURDATE()
     ) AS tb3x
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      tb1y.id,
      tb1y.created
    FROM table1 AS tb1y
      JOIN table2 AS tb2y
        ON tb2y.id = tb1y.cid
    WHERE tb1y.created < CURDATE()
  ) AS tb3y

    ON tb3x.id = tb3y.id
ORDER BY tb3y.created DESC;
```

Another thing is collect all rows in one table before and after a certain time. You need to use `UNION` of two sub-query table, each of which is a filter of the input table:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  (
    SELECT
      tb1x.id,
      tb1x.created
    FROM table1 AS tb1x
      JOIN table2 AS tb2x
        ON tb2x.id = tb1x.cid
    WHERE tb1x.created > CURDATE()
  )
  UNION ALL
  (
    SELECT
      tb1y.id,
      tb1y.created
    FROM table1 AS tb1y
      JOIN table2 AS tb2y
        ON tb2y.id = tb1y.cid
    WHERE tb1y.created < CURDATE()
  )
)
ORDER BY created DESC;
```

Comment: I need a kind of **UNION ALL**  which gives me the posibility to check ON **tb3x.id = tb3y.id**,  however none of your answer will take me to that point!

Comment: Can you explain me with a data input/output example?

Comment: I think the problem is not because of input/output, for example when I use UNION ALL it gives me this error : **Every derived table must have its own alias** which is related to **as whatever**

Comment: I could fix the problem by combining both union method and join method!

Comment: Can you share the fix?